# Jquery Slider is not working with Magento 1.6.2 in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery

I downloaded Wowslider in order to achieve the slider effect on my home page. 
In the magento backend: 
Content section of my home page (CMS->PAGES), I pasted in the following code:

```
<!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#s3slider').s3Slider({
        timeOut: 4000
    });
});
// ]]>
</script>
<div id="wowslider-container1">
<div class="ws_images">
<ul>
<li><img id="wows0" title="Blue hills" src="data1/images/blue_hills.jpg" alt="Blue     hills" /></li>
<li><img id="wows1" title="Sunset" src="data1/images/sunset.jpg" alt="Sunset" /></li>
<li><img id="wows2" title="Water lilies" src="data1/images/water_lilies.jpg" alt="Water lilies" /></li>
<li><img id="wows3" title="Winter" src="data1/images/winter.jpg" alt="Winter" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="ws_bullets">
<div><a title="Blue hills" href="#"><img src="data1/tooltips/blue_hills.jpg" alt="Blue hills" />1</a> <a title="Sunset" href="#"><img src="data1/tooltips/sunset.jpg" alt="Sunset" />2</a> <a title="Water lilies" href="#"><img src="data1/tooltips  /water_lilies.jpg" alt="Water lilies" />3</a> <a title="Winter" href="#"><img src="data1/tooltips/winter.jpg" alt="Winter" />4</a></div>
</div>
<a class="wsl" href="http://wowslider.com">HTML Slideshow Code Generator by WOWSlider.com v2.1.3</a> <a class="ws_frame" href="#"></a></div>
<script src="engine1/wowslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="engine1/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
```

---

In the page.xml, the last line of the code below is added by me:

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

<!--the following 1 line is added by myself -->
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>skin/frontend/newdefault/default/js/jquery.js</name></action>
```

The result is that the slider is working in Firefox and chrome, but not in IE (it's static in IE and just show 1 image)

I have tried other plugins as well for sliding effect, and all seems working in firefox or Chrome but not in IE.

Comment: What error message(s) are you getting in IE? What version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with JQuery not working in Internet Explorer myself. I'm not positive that this is the solution that will work for you, but it's worth a try.

In /app/design/frontend/default//template/page/html there may be script tag around line 49 that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you're lucky enough to use a theme that pulls in JQuery itself, then this line should be present. You may know that 1.3.2 is an old JQuery version. If you change the 1.3.2 to 1.5.1 it  should work, or at least it did for me.

I hope this helps, I spent a long time tracking this down for myself, I hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

The [first Google result](http://www.wowslider.com/rq/carousel-image-has-problem-with-displaying-in-internet-explorer-t.html) for "wow slider internet explorer" yielded the following information:

> Q: I have purchased version 2 of the WOWSlider and have discovered the
>   following problem. When I cut and paste the code into a table, the
>   slider will no longer show when viewed in Internet Explorer although
>   seems to work perfectly in the other browsers. This is extremely
>   frustrating as I need to use tables so as to centre my website. Please
>   give me some advice. Thank you.
>
> A: Try to add the DOCTYPE declaration for universal compatibility:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

> If problem will persist, please send us a direct link to your website
>   at support [at] wowslider [dot] com, so we can check it. Write us also
>   what version of IE browser do you use.

Comment: I have tried paste <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> in the design section of my CMS->Page in Magento and it's still not working.....